# Is it true that the word "some" can mean two things?

Tags: difference

Let's take the sentence "I ate **some** meat" for example. Am I correct thinking that it can mean two things, either *"I ate **some amount** of meat"*, or *"I ate **some kind** of meat, don't know which  exactly it was, but I know it was meat"*

Comment: Yes, both are correct.

Comment: The first is much more likely; the second is possible, but would be spoken with emphasis on _some_.

Comment: some amount of meat cannot be two things as it is not a countable noun here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "some" can be used to refer to something or someone that is unspecified or undetermined. A better example for the second case is:

> I was talking to *some* guy the other day.

"Some" can also mean "a really great", as in "Some pig" (from the story Charlotte's web)

Comment: "Some" can also mean "a really great",  as in "Some pig" (from the story Charlotte's web)

Comment: @JamesK Yes, you made a good point there.

Comment: Thank's Ali,  The intention of commenting is that you can incorporate my comment into your answer.  You can copy+paste, or write in your own words, then I can delete the comment.  Or you can ignore my comment, its up to you.  A purpose of comments is to "suggest improvements"

Comment: @JamesK You are right, i updated my answer. Thank you for your suggestion.